# Start GUI-Application in Docker Container with sudo

Tags: 16.04, sudo, xserver, docker, display-manager

System: Ubuntu 16.04
Display-Manager: lightdm

I'm trying to create a docker container `FROM ubuntu:latest` where a GUI-Application is running in.
The application needs to get executed with sudo to access the inside used commands.
I followed the instruction of [this](http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/) Blog and adapted it for my use.

After i build this container I first ran it with:

```
docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix repo-test-3 /bin/bash
```

then

```
./application
```

and the application is shown at the screen.

The next I tried to run the same container with `-u 0` to become root and after i tried to start the application the following error message appears:

```
No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Do you have any idea whats the problem and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

Give docker the rights to access the X-Server with:

```
xhost +local:docker
```