# How to install 2 telegram desktop on a ubuntu pc?

Tags: 16.04, telegram

I have 2 Telegram accounts and i want to have both of them on my pc.
Telegram has an [application](https://desktop.telegram.org/) for ubuntu. but it only supports one account at the time.

My question is,
How can i duplicate this application to use 2 Telegram account?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run Telegram with a custom "working directory":

```
mkdir tel_account2

Telegram -many -workdir tel_account2
```

Answer (score 0):

Download [Franz](http://meetfranz.com/). It allows you to run multiple accounts. It comes as a tgz file. Right click on it and Extract it. Open the extracted folder. Run **Franz** application. On the Franz windows you can see multiple account types and select Telegram.Give a name to your new Telegram.You can login to your new Telegram account in the new tab in Franz

Comment: Thank you but i only want to use the official telegram application. i want somehow duplicate the application.

Comment: Franz says it allows you to add one service many times. That means you are running the same Telegram service another instance.

Comment: This a proprietary, closed source software ? You seem to have erred on the wrong side of FOSS.

Answer (score 0):

1. First go to [Telegram website](https://desktop.telegram.org/) and download Telegram tar.xz package. Extract it. Open the extracted folder. Then run Telegram application in the extracted folder.
2. If you are running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS you can install Telegram snap package too. Open the terminal and enter the below command and hit enter. Enter your password when prompted:

   ```bsh
   sudo snap install telegram-sergiusens
   ```

   This will install Telegram snap package. You can use both of these separately.

Comment: Thank you but i can not run the snap package.
i run: telegram-sergiusens.telegram on terminal and this is what it shows me:

Comment: No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Telegram(main+0xb1)[0x67df31]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f3f9f22c830]
Telegram[0x692aed]
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Actually I have no idea about that error. But that method worked for me and I can run two Telegram at the same time. See if this helps. http://askubuntu.com/questions/793100/start-gui-application-in-docker-container-with-sudo